# VB Textbox accept only numbers prob

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub TextBox1_textChange(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim intValue As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, intValue) OrElse intValue < 1 OrElse intValue > 10 Then
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox(intValue)


    End If

End Sub
```

here is my code , the textbox already accepts number only, when i press `"1"` the `textbox1.text = "1"`, but when i press AGAIN the `"1"` the first `"1"` is being overwrite .. same with the when i press `"2"` the textbox1.text is now only equal to `"2"`..

help please?

Comment: you go to keypress event.

Answer (score 1):

Better handle the `KeyPress` event to achieve the needed functionality

```
Private Sub DigitTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    'Just Digits
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    'Allow Backspace
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It lloks like the code is checking that the textbox has values 1-10.  If so this will work

```
    Dim intValue As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, intValue) AndAlso intValue > 0 AndAlso intValue < 11 Then
        Debug.WriteLine(intValue) 'good value
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "" 'bad value
    End If
```